How to read just one line from a TXT file?
I'm creating a Wordle-like game and I need to create a dictionary in a TXT file. At the moment I'm just using a vector in my script.js file.
The idea is to have one word on each line like this:
ANGEL
APPLE
HELLO
...

I created the .txt and am reading it from my JS
import { readFile } from "fs"; 
readFile("dictionary.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    const randomLine = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)];
    console.log(randomLine);
  });



what is that variable lines?

Use const lines = data.split('\n')

I am not sure if there is real necessity to deal with file and store as text. I would recommend changing file structure to json and have array there.
Example:


import words from'./words.json' assert { type: "json" };

const randomIndex= Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length);

console.log(words[randomIndex])




import { readFile } from "fs";

// Reading the file
readFile("dictionary.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  
  // Splitting the file content into lines
  const lines = data.trim().split("\n");

  // Choosing a random line
  const randomLine = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)].trim();

  console.log(randomLine); // Logs the randomly chosen line
});

This code reads the dictionary.txt file, splits ("\n") its content into lines, selects a random line, and logs it to the console.
